# Three js AR mode configuration could not be installed

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, chromium

I'm having
`Could not create a session because runtime for this configuration could not be installed`
console error and cannot enter ar mode on my mobile device
I've checked whether my device supports xr, it does
But I cant understand what is wrong with configuration
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm running localhost with https flag on hotspot from my mobile phone
And enabled experimental XR features flag, I guess its not the thing I needed to set

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)